# cmake для arm и x86

Tags: c++, cmake, arm

Есть проект, который необходимо собирать под две платформы x86 и arm7.

для каждой платформы в отдельности CMakeLists выглядит примерно так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(asio_test_x86)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(boost_libdir_x86 "/path2boost/boost86/lib")
include_directories("/path2boost/boost86/include")

find_library(x86_LBSys boost_system PATH ${boost_libdir_x86})
find_library(x86_LBThread boost_thread PATH ${boost_libdir_x86})

set (LIBRARYS_x86)
list (APPEND LIBRARYS_x86 ${x86_LBSys} ${x86_LBThread})

add_executable(asio_test_x86 ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(asio_test_x86 ${LIBRARYS_x86})
```

И для arm

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(asio_test_arm)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(boost_libdir_arm "/path2boost/boostarm/lib")
include_directories("/path2boost/boostarm/include")

find_library(arm_LBSys boost_system PATH ${boost_libdir_arm})
find_library(arm_LBThread boost_thread PATH ${boost_libdir_arm})

set (LIBRARYS_arm)
list (APPEND LIBRARYS_arm ${arm_LBSys} ${arm_LBThread})

add_executable(asio_test_arm ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(asio_test_x86 ${LIBRARYS_arm})
```

Исходники одни и те же, разница только в компиляторах и версиях Boost.
Можно ли как-то написать общий cmake файл, чтобы собирать одной командой?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Используйте CMake Toolchain File:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html
- http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file

в тулчейне можно определить нужные переменные и использовать их для ветвления в основном CMakeLists.txt. Либо объявлять пути, просто используя общие переменные, а в основном CMakeLists.txt просто ссылаться на них.

Либо, как вариант, компилятор можно переопределять через переменную окружения `CC`, `CXX` при вызове cmake, а остальные опции задавать через `-DПАРАМЕТР=значение` и использовать условия внутри CMakeLists.txt, например:

```
env CXX=/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ \
    cmake -DBOOST_PREFIX=/path2boost/boostarm
```

а внутри:

```
set(boost_libdir "${BOOST_PREFIX}/lib")
include_directories("${BOOST_PREFIX}/include")
```

но лучше через тулчейн. Хотя, мне больше импонирует вариант использования какого-то дефолта (с возможностью переопределить через `-DPARAM=VAL`) для хост-машины и использование тулчейнов для различных вариантов кросс-билда.